# API POST http://localhost:3000/[object%20Object]

Tags: javascript, stripe-payments

I am making the payment app with stripe. (base on the stripe [repo](https://github.com/tmarek-stripe/demo-react-stripe-js))

I made server.js with express.

When I clicked the pay button is clicked, console shows `xhr.js:177 POST http://localhost:3000/[object%20Object] 404 (Not Found)` 
this error.

[image]

```
server.js
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const path = require('path');
if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') require('dotenv').config();
const stripe = require('stripe')(process.env.SECRET_KEY);

const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.use(cors());

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'client/build')));

  app.get('*', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'client/build', 'index.html'));
  });
}
app.listen(port, error => {
  if (error) throw error;
  console.log('server running on port' + port);
});

app.post('/pay', async (req, res) => {
  if (req.method === 'POST') {
    try {
      const { amount } = req.body;
      const paymentIntent = await stripe.paymentIntents.create({
        amount,
        currency: 'usd',
      });
      res.status(200).send(paymentIntent.client_secret);
    } catch (err) {
      res.status(500).json({ statusCode: 500, message: err.message });
    }
  } else {
    res.setHeader('Allow', 'POST');
    res.status(405).end('Method Not Allowed');
  }
});
```

this is the checkout form

```
Checkoutform.js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { CardElement, useStripe, useElements } from '@stripe/react-stripe-js';
import BillingDetailsFields from './BillingDetailForm';
import axios from 'axios';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import payment_intents from './api/payment_intents';

const CheckoutForm = ({ price, onSuccessfulCheckout }) => {
  const [isProcessing, setProcessingTo] = useState(false);
  const [checkoutError, setCheckoutError] = useState();

  const stripe = useStripe();
  const elements = useElements();

  const handleCardDetailsChange = ev => {
    ev.error ? setCheckoutError(ev.error.message) : setCheckoutError();
  };
  const handleFormSubmit = async e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const billingDetails = {
      name: e.target.name.value,
      email: e.target.email.value,
      address: {
        city: e.target.city.value,
        line1: e.target.address.value,
        state: e.target.state.value,
        postal_code: e.target.zip.value,
      },
    };

    setProcessingTo(true);

    const cardElement = elements.getElement('card');

    try {
    const { data: clientSecret } = await axios.post(
      { payment_intents },
      {
        amount: price,
      }
    );
    console.log(clientSecret);

    const paymentMethodReq = await stripe.createPaymentMethod({
      type: 'card',
      card: cardElement,
      billing_details: billingDetails,
    });

    if (paymentMethodReq.error) {
      setCheckoutError(paymentMethodReq.error.message);
      setProcessingTo(false);
      return;
    }

    const { error } = await stripe.confirmCardPayment(clientSecret, {
      payment_method: paymentMethodReq.paymentMethod.id,
    });

    if (error) {
      setCheckoutError(error.message);
      setProcessingTo(false);
      return;
    }

    onSuccessfulCheckout();
    } catch (err) {
      setCheckoutError(err.message);
    }
  };
  const cardElementOpts = {
    hidePostalCode: true,
  };
  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleFormSubmit}>
      <div>
        <CheckoutTitle>Pay with</CheckoutTitle>
        <BillingDetailsFields />
      </div>
      <div>
        <CardElementContainer>
          <CardElement
            option={cardElementOpts}
            onChange={handleCardDetailsChange}
          />
        </CardElementContainer>
      </div>
      <div>
        <PayBtn disabled={isProcessing || !stripe}>
          {isProcessing ? 'Processing...' : `Confirm and Pay`}
        </PayBtn>
      </div>
    </form>
  );
};
```

I think there is an issue with the app.post('/pay', async (req, res) => {}
But I really don't know what is the problem.

Comment: when you send a request in the frontend, you didn't send it with `/pay` but you define the post in server as `/pay`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! So should I made the pay component and link it together?? @ikhvjs

Comment: You should do something like `axios.post('/pay` in your frontend.

Comment: Oh! Thank you I update the code base what you said. Now there are other issue : POST http://localhost:3000/pay 404 (Not Found)   << It caused there is no pay component??

Comment: A suggestion. Before you touch your frontend code, you should try to use some tools like postman or insomnia to test your backend first. To check if your backend can respond correctly before you working on your frotnend.

Comment: Are you defining `process.env.PORT` when starting your Express server? If not, it'll be running on `:5000`, not `:3000` which is seemingly a mismatch from your React application (which is on `:3000`).